# Question about derivative proof :)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose that $3 ≤ f'(x) ≤ 5$, for all values of $x$, please show that $18 ≤ f(8)-f(2) ≤ 30$.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. Questions that are clearly homework and show no work of your own are discouraged on this site. You can [take the tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more. I will give you a hint anyways: Try the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 2):

I'll set it up for you the other way: By the mean value theorem, there is $c\in (2,8)$ such that
$$
f'(c) = \frac {f(8)-f(2)} {8-2}.
$$
Now do some arithmetic, and your result follows.

Comment: This is probably the better answer out of the two of ours since it doesn't assume knowledge of integration. $+1$!

Comment: @Cameron Hey, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'll set it up for you. Define $g(x) = 5-f'(x)$. Then $g(x)\ge 0$ by your hypothesis. $\int_2^8 g(x)\,dx \ge 0$ since $g$ is non-negative. Can you take it from here?